# algorithm to distribute points between 3 "buckets"

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I'm attempting to write an algorithm to distribute 100 weighting points between X number of rules in a system, where the rules have one of Y different weights. For example:

If I have 9 rules in the system, with 3 rules set to high priority, 2 rules set to medium priority, and 4 rules set to low priority, the points would be distributed like so:

```
High (3x) - 20 per rule (60 points)

Med (2x) - 10 per rule (20 points)

Low (4x) - 5 per rule (20 points)
```

**For a total of 100 points**

All weights may not always exists. For example, there could be 1 high rule and 1 low, 1 medium rule (which would get all 100 points), etc.

I have not been able to figure out a way to make this work, partially because I don't know what this type of operation is called. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: > If I have 6 rules in the system, with 3 rules set to high priority, 2 rules set to medium priority, and 4 rules set to low priority
Did you mean 9 rules?

Comment: I did. I'll edit the question.

Comment: You said 'Y' weights, but in the rest of your post, there's always three weights (corresponding to 'High', 'Medium' and 'Low'). Is this just an example and are you looking for a solution that would also cover two, four or really any number of weightings?

Comment: We currently have 3 weights but it is possible that we could add more going forward and I'd like my solution to accommodate that if possible.

Comment: May I assume that the weights need not be in straightforward 1/2/4 ratios?

Comment: That's correct, but the weights do need to be proportional (so I can't give low a weight of 1, med a weight of 2, and split the rest between high, for example).

Comment: @BrentWaggoner And what happens if the total doesn't divide 100 evenly?  For example if there are 3 rules of the same weight, do you want a split of 33/33/33 or 34/33/33?

Comment: Decimals are ok. My initial solution before I asked this question ended up with some .0000001s unaccounted for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may sum up your rules weights (`S = sum(rule_num[i] * rule_weight[i])`) and compare that with 100. Instead of assigning 1 point to a rule you should assign `100/S` points per rule.

```
rule_weights = (20, 10, 5)
rule_counts = (3, 2, 4)
s = sum([w * c for (w, c) in zip(rule_weights, rule_counts)])
assignment = [100 / s * w * c for (w, c) in zip(rule_weights, rule_counts)]
```

That is up to you what to do in case of non-integer number of points.

Comment: This looks close to what I want. Could you update your answer with a short snippet of code that distributes some points? I'm having trouble visualizing the implementation.

Comment: This answer ended up giving me what I needed to solve my problem. Thanks!